# for loop not picking up the array length properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
                this.videos[i].url = 'http://localhost:27017/' + 
this.videos[i].url;
            this.videos[i].avgRating = 0;
            for(var j=0;j<this.videos[i].rating.length;j++){
                this.videos[i].avgRating += this.videos[i].rating[j];
            }
```

Second for loop is causing an error "Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: `this.videos[i].rating` is undefined

Comment: can you console.log(this.videos[i].rating) and see if the value exists

Comment: You should use `i < videos.length` instead of a hardcoded number.

Comment: It seems that `this.videos[i].rating` is undefined or null. Have you tried to log `this.videos[i]` to the console and checked the value?

Comment: i will try to check the value in rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that 'rating' is uninitialized in the 'i'th video element.  Have you verified that your videos array was fully initialized before hitting the outer loop?

Comment: That's exactly what happened, one of the models was missing a letter in one of its data members, so that field did not pick up the data from the HTTP call and was null.  Thank you, really helped knowing where to look for the problem.